# Mustache Rendering Issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I'm just getting started using Mustache and I have this rendering problem. I send the data through a render function:

```
return Mustache.render(html, data);
```

or

```
return Mustache.to_html(html, data);
```

But the when I append it to a div like:

```
$('#jqt').append(html);
```

It gives back results like this, in actual text:

```
<div id="product_search_view">&lt;form class="search-form" &gt;&lt;ul class="rounded"&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;input type="text" id="label" name="search" placeholder="Enter what you are looking for"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="whiteButton submit" id="search-button" &gt;Search&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/form&gt;&lt;ul id="search-results" class="edgetoedge"&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</div>
```

How can I get mustache not to put in those characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like you passed an already parsed HTML to Mustache.

Here's [a section of the documentation](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache#escaping) that addresses escaped characters and the use of the "triple mustache".

Also, [here's another documentation](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html). Read the Tag Types section and the use of the `&` to prevent escaping.

Comment: tripple mustache `{{{UnescapedStuffFromMustache}}}` works great!

Answer (score 0):

I also got this weird issue last time, and I got to this hacky solution from somewhere

```
var temp = Mustache.to_html(template, data_sources );

var correct_temp = $('<textarea />').html(temp).val();

$('#my_el').html(correct_temp);
```

Don't know if it's a good practice.